# Design tree in a more efficient way and exhaustively search it

Tags: algorithm, matlab, search, data-structures, tree

I want to exhaustively search all the possible outcomes as shown in the following algorithm:

```
for trace=1:2^(t*M)
    R=0;
    for i=1:t
        for j=1:M
            if obs(i,j)
               %%do something and calculate E
               R=R+getReward(E);%this calls a function
            end
        end
    end
   outcome(trace,:)=R;
end
finalResult=max(outcome);
```

`obs(i,j)` is a matrix designed as follows:

```
%%Outside of loops
Matrix = dec2bin(0:2^(t*M)-1)-'0';
myMatrix = reshape(Matrix.',t,M,[]);
%%inside the big loop
obs=myMatrix(:,:,trace)
```

This basically creates all the possible combinations of binary matrices in order to produce an outcome for all the different combinations of a binary matrix based on `t` and `M`. Obviously, if `t` and `M` are large, the initial `Matrix` cannot be created as it requires enormous amount of memory. Even if you allocate memory though, it takes ages to run for even relatively small values of `t` and `M`. My question is how to more efficiently redesign this algorithm to run with the following setting: for example `t=100` and `M=10`.  You can also see this as a tree (say `M=2` and `t=2`). `t` is the depth of the tree and `M` the number of binary elements within each node. So, for `t=1` we will have the following nodes:`n1=00 n2=01 n3=10 n4=11`. At `t=2`, this exponentially increases to `2^(t*M)`. So, I am asking whether another approach instead of making a matrix with all binary combinations would be better or whether there is another standard algorithm to do this kind of search.

If you have any questions or need any clarifications please let me know. Any comments are also welcomed.